# Knowing the type of the stored proc when invoking from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am making a windows service to be able to run operations on a sql server database (insert, edit, etc) and invoke Stored Procs.

However, is there a way for me to know the type of the SP? When invoking from C#, I need to knof if it is returning 1 value, or more, or none (so I can use executereader, scalar, etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A **non-query** is usually called with `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. But it's valid to run it as `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.  The only difference is that the first call to `DataReader.Read()` returns `false` for a stored procedure that does not return a resultset.
2. A **rowset** is run as `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.  The first call to `DataReader.Read()` will return `true`.
3. A **scalar** is just a shortcut for a rowset with one column and one row.

So you can use `ExecuteReader` in all three scenarios.

Though it seems unnecessary for your question, you can retrieve meta-data for the resultset using the [fmtonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspxF) option.  The setting causes the statement to return the column information only; no rows of data are returned.  So you could run:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
EXEC dbo.YourProc @par1 = 1;
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Executing this as a `CommandText` from C#, you can examine the column names the stored procedure would return.

To verify that a stored procedure run in this way does not produce any side effects, I ran  the following test case:

```
create table table1 (id int)
go
create procedure YourProc(@par1 int)
as
insert into table1 (id) values (@par1)
go
SET FMTONLY ON;
EXEC dbo.YourProc @par1 = 1;
SET FMTONLY OFF;
go
select * from table1
```

This did not return any rows.  So the format-only option makes sure no actual updates or inserts occur.